# Firebase Download Task Queue Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uiviewcontroller, firebase-storage

I am currently downloading image files from Firebase Storage with the code below for the thumbnails in a `UICollectionView`.When I tap on one of the thumbnails, the app segues to another `UIViewController` that then downloads more images from Firebase Storage.
Currently the app waits for all of the thumbnails to finish downloading before downloading the next images in the `UIViewController`. Is it possible to increase the priority of the new images in the `UIViewController` or cancel all other downloads to start the new ones immediately?

```
var imageRef = storageRef.child("Thumbnails/\(itemID).jpg")
imageRef.getData(maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error 
    if let error = error {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
     } else {
        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
        self.newsNameArray.append(name)
        self.newsImageArray.append(image!)
        self.newsBarCollectionView?.reloadData()                        
      }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a reference to a StorageDownloadTask like this:

```
var allTasks: [StorageDownloadTask] = []

var imageRef = storageRef.child("Thumbnails/\(itemID).jpg")
let downloadTask = imageRef.getData(maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error 
    if let error = error {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
     } else {
        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
        self.newsNameArray.append(name)
        self.newsImageArray.append(image!)
        self.newsBarCollectionView?.reloadData()                        
      }
}
```

Store your downloadTasks in an array and cancel all tasks before downloading the new images:

```
allTasks.append(downloadTask)

...

for task in allTasks {
    task.cancel()
}
```